# Print contents of an array and their key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

so currently I have a PHP function that prints out the applications configuration:

```
function cconfig() {
global $config;
// If the user wants debug information shown:
if (SHOWDEBUG == true) {
    // If there is config information to show
    if (isset($config)) {
        cout("Variable &#36;config is set.", "debug");
        foreach ($config as $current) {
            echo $current."<br/>";
        }
    } else {
        cout("Variable &#36;config isn't set.", "debug");
    }
}
```

}

The output only shows the values of the array that it's at `$current`. For example:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

How can I edit this function so instead of just showing the value at a given key, it also shows the key?

```
ConfigEntry1 = Value1
ConfigEntry2 = Value2
ConfigEntry3 = Value3
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose the key like so:

```
foreach ($config as $k => $v) {
    echo $k. ' ' . $v ."<br/>";
}
```

The two forms a foreach can take, from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

> The first form loops over the array
>   given by array_expression. On each
>   loop, the value of the current element
>   is assigned to $value and the internal
>   array pointer is advanced by one (so
>   on the next loop, you'll be looking at
>   the next element).
>
> **The second form does the same thing, except that the current element's key
>   will be assigned to the variable $key
>   on each loop.**

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. I must wait before I can accept your answer though.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($config as $key => $current) {
    echo "$key = $current<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
foreach ($config as $current) {
        echo $current."<br/>";
    }
```

to

```
foreach ($config as $key => $val) {
        echo $key." = " . $val . "<br/>";
    }
```